# Swapping structures using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, structure

Suppose we have a structure like the following:

```
struct EMPLOYEE{

   int EmpID;
   int Sal;

} Stu[5];
```

And we wish to swap these structures if the following condition is true:

`Stu[i].Sal < Stu[0].Sal`

One way way could be by swapping the whole stucture. Something like this:

```
TempStu.Sal = Stu[i].Sal;
Stu[i].Sal = Stu[0].Sal;
Stu[0].Sal = TempStu.Sal;

TempStu.EmpID = Stu[i].EmpID;
Stu[i].EmpID = Stu[0].EmpID;
Stu[0].EmpID = Temp.Stu.EmpID;
```

This makes it a very time consuming method. 
Other method could be using an array of pointers to EMPLOYEE structs and then sort these pointers only. I'm unable to figure out how to do the this.

Here is a start I made..

```
EMPLOYEE *St[5];

for(int j=0; j<5; j++) {

   St[j] = &Stu[j];

}

if(Stu[i].Sal < Stu[0].Sal) 
   swap(St[i],St[0]);

void swap(EMPLOYEE *A, EMPLOYEE *B) {

    EMPLOYEE temp = *A;
    *A = *B;
    *B = temp;
}
```

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: `std::swap(Stu[i], Stu[0]);`

Comment: Are you using C or C++?

Comment: @EdHeal C. Does it matter in this case, though? The logic should apply to both the cases, right? I'm new to this.

Comment: @K_K - Yes it does matter - the option above is for C++ i.e. not C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a correct approach?

Almost. In `swap()`, you need to use pointers to pointers (or references to pointers in C++). Otherwise the changes you make to `A` and `B` don't propagate back to the caller.

Comment: Of course! In my case I was only working on variables local to that function. (A case of argument by reference vs argument by value, right?) 
@tesseract in his answer has implemented what you had meant.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is correct, but your only swapping two local pointers in your function.

try this

```
if(Stu[i].Sal < Stu[0].Sal) 

swap(&St[i],&St[0]);//pass the addresses

void swap(EMPLOYEE **A, EMPLOYEE **B) {

EMPLOYEE *temp = *A;
*A = *B;
*B = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void swap(EMPLOYEE* arr[],int i,int j)
{
    EMPLOYEE* temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}

if (Stu[i].Sal < Stu[0].Sal)
    swap(Stu,i,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use array, you can swap struct through each field you can not use pointer. because the nature of the array is a series of consecutive memory cells. You only change the value inside the pointer but not swap the position of the struct.

1. [image: List item]
2. [image: List item]
3. [image: List item]

   You should use the linked list. Because its locations are dynamic, you can swap its

Comment: It will be fun when I get your comments !