# How does the second method work (swapping structures)?

Tags: c, struct, swap

This is about swapping structures in c. 
I have a question about the second method,both are working according to many sources(like this one [Swapping structures using pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968548/swapping-structures-using-pointers)):
(student is the name of the struct in my program)

APPROACH 1:

```
void swap(student *a,student *b)
{
student temp=*a;
*a=*b;
*b=temp;
}
```

This how i interpret it: A temporary structure stores a. And a gets the content of b in the next statement. And we store content of temp in b. Cool.
The above approach is very clear to me.
Now,
APPROACH 2:

```
void swap(student *a,student *b)
{
student *temp=a;
*a=*b;
*b=*temp;
}
```

This seems to be working. But i have a question.
This is how i interpret this code: In the first step temp is assigned the address pointed by a. In the next step we change the content of the address of a to the content of b. Now the location pointed by a holds content of b. In the next step, we access content of temp (temp holds address of a) which was changed to content of b earlier. So both the variables gets content of b. 
THEN HOW DOES THIS METHOD WORK?

Comment: As far as I know, `t` and `temp` used to be separate variables....

Comment: Sorry for that. Edited.

Comment: @SubinP Why do you think it work?

Comment: (Assuming `t` and `temp` are meant to be the same thing:) Unless I'm misreading the code, the first method is correct, and the second method is wrong.  The second method should, as you expect, leave both `*a` and `*b` containing the original contents of `*b`.  If it appears to work, there must be something else going on.  Please follow the advice at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please provide some evidence that your "APPROACH 2" works.  Saving the value of the pointer won't save the value of the structure `a` contents.

Comment: I found it here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968548/swapping-structures-using-pointers

Answer (score 2):

The second method doesn't work.  It sets both to the contents of `b`, just as you described:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct student {
    char x;
} student;

void swap(student *a,student *b)
{
    student *temp=a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=*temp;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    student a, b;
    a.x='a';
    b.x='b';
    printf("a.x=%c, b.x=%c\n",a.x,b.x);
    swap(&a,&b);
    printf("a.x=%c, b.x=%c\n",a.x,b.x);
}
```

Output:

```
a.x=a, b.x=b
a.x=b, b.x=b
```

Comment: Thanks, its clear now.. btw, i found the second method here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968548/swapping-structures-using-pointers.. its obviously wrong then.

Comment: @SubinP You misread those methods.  There are additional levels in indirection in those examples that make it work that your example doesn't have.

Answer (score 2):

The correct second approach:

```
void swap(student **a,student **b)
{
    student *temp=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}
```

Where the object are not moved but only the pointers are swapped.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work. The reason is the use of `student *temp;`. This is a *pointer* to a student. When you assign `a` to it, you let it *point* to `a` and you haven't saved the contents of `a`.

Then with `*a=*b` the contents of `a` is overwritten. Now with `*b=*temp` you overwrite the contents of `b` with the contents of what `temp` points to, which is `a`, which just got the contents of `b`.